# Microsoft Access listbox bring to front

Tags: ms-access

I have two list boxes in a form. One of them is bigger than other. Smaller one was placed at the back of bigger one. I tried position > bring front for smaller one and position > send back for bigger one, but didn't work. Also, tried to change Tab index in Other menu and wrote codes Me.Repaint and Me.List.SetFocus but they didn't work neither. Is there any way to change to bring smaller list front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking on the listbox and select Position -> bring to front should work (in Access 2013), but the layout of two listboxes are a bit messed up then.

A Listbox is not ment to be on another listbox, and I cannot imagine why you want to do this. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: From row source, I'm gettin two different data from two different queries. There are blank lines in bigger list and to fill that data, I'm trying to get data from other query into smaller list. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'll look for layout part. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure if I understand your problem correctly. Are you trying to update a row in a listbox where the values comes from a listbox that is in that row? I don't think you can fill a listbox with another listbox. I think you'll be better of with a subform and on that subform (for the biggest list) you can place the listbox per row.